# Perform the sum between two raster, one of which has a value of "nodata" or "null" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, nodata

I have two raster (raster1 and raster2) from the same area. I would like to make the sum between the two (`raster3 = raster1 + raster2`) in QGIS, so that the Digital Number (DN) of raster 3 is the sum between them.
However, raster2 has some pixels like "`nodata`" or "`null`" without data. When I add them together, the "nodata" pixels do not add up.

For example: `raster1 = 2` and `raster2 = nodata`. When I add these, the result is `nodata` (`2 + nodata = nodata`), but I expected it to be `= 2`, that is, (`2 + nodata = 2`).

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start QGIS with GRASS and then run `r.null` from processing toolbox on your nodata raster and convert all `NULL` values to `0` values. Then you should be able to build your sum in raster calculator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello @MrXsquared, i tried apply you answer, but not the result yet returns pixels with nodata.

Comment: @wesleysc352 That shouldnt be the case. I have attached a short GIF to illustrate.

Comment: hello @MrXsquared,thanks for the immense help. I had filled in the wrong field. Now it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I would note that the GRASS module `r.mapcalc` allows you to add rasters, while ignoring NULL cells, without changing the original. For example:

`r.mapcalc "raster3 = if(isnull(raster1), raster2, raster1 + raster2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use *r.series*:

```
r.series input=raster1,raster2 output=raster3 method=sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Fill NoData cells`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#fill-nodata-cells) to remove `NoData` values from a raster: you can choose a value the `No Data` cells are replaced with.

Hot to find the tool:

```
Menu Processing > Toolbox > Fill NoData cells
```

Answer (score 0):

The SAGA tool "Rasters Sum" has a simple option for counting 'no data' values as zero.

`SAGA > Raster - Calculus > Rasters Sum`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The SAGA tool "Change a grid's No-Data value" also helps.

In the Processing panel:

`SAGA > Raster - Tools > Change a Grid's No-Data Value`

[image]